# Is there a Rails way to check which attributes have been updated in an observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, observer-pattern

I have an `ActivityObserver`, which is observing `tasks`, and has an `after_update` callback.

I want to test if a particular attribute has been modified in the `update`.

Is there a Rails way to compare the attributes of the subject with what they were before the update, or to check if they have changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an after_update callback is being executed, every ActiveModel object has a method called `changed_attributes`. You can check it out in your debug environment. Every ActiveRecord object has this method. It has a hash of all the values that have been changed/modified. This is also known as Dirty object.

Check out some of these tutorials

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes)

[Dirty Object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: Thanks! No matter how much Rails dev I do, there's always something new to learn.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something like following in your observer.

```
class ActivityObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_update(activity)
    if activity.attribute_name_changed?
      puts "The above condition will return true or false, and this time it has returned true..!!!"
    end
  end

end
```

The above method will do. I think you were looking for this ..